# Flask collect data in parallel and make list

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, python-requests

My flask application works. It checks the health status of a heart monitor (Supervised by a docter with a ID) and it collects the doctors current activities. Bellow I show a part of the code that I wrote (in python in ubuntu). However What I want is this:

- We receive the ID (ID of the docter) that the user filled in the Web browser
- Then perform the **2 activities in parallel**: we collect the health scores and the second activity can happen in parallel because we already know the ID of the docter: We can automatically check the activities of the doctor at the moment.
- I make a list where I merge these scores together.

How can I make my code parallel? The two servers are independent from each other. Because now I wait till I get the hearth monitor then the doctors it's activities. Before the request I am doing some search operations and after the request I do some heavy calculations, so I am looking for a Parallel programming/CPU Intensive type of solutions.

```
@app.route('/getstatus',methods=['POST','GET'])
def get_score():
    if request.method=='POST':
    #we wait till the web user has filled in the ID of the doctor
        id = request.form['id']

        #hearthmonitor Processor 1 parallelactivity 1 before the request I am searching the servername of the hearthmonitor that belongs with the ID
        urlhearth=serverhearth+id
        rh= requests.get(serverhearth, allow_redirects=False)
        h1=rh.content


        #doctormonitor Processor 2 parallelactivity 2 before the request I am searching the servername of the doctorserver (department server) that belongs with the ID. This is what I want to run in parrallel with activity 1   
        urldoc=server+id
        rd= requests.get(urldoc, allow_redirects=False)
        d1= rd.content



        #we make a list of their outcomes together
        list=[doctor, hearth]
```

Comment: You appear to be using the Python Requests library.  Some projects to make asynchronous requests with that library are linked in its [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#blocking-or-non-blocking).

Comment: It is not only about the request. After the request of the doctor for example we count the numbers of words that he typed in the computer for the last two hours and we  calculate the average. The request is just a small part.